# How can you tag a FB page follower, member or participant in a comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, comments, facebook-tags

I'm asking this because I've seen page admins who answer a person tagging him/her on their comments.

Sometimes I comment on a page I haven't even "like" it, and the admi is able to tag me in his comment anyway.

That means I'm not even a member of the page but they're able to tag me.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Admin (or any other person) can tag anyone who has participated in a discussion regardless of their connection status with the person being referenced. On the other hand, Pages (a person using Facebook as a Page) can tag only other Pages or Groups (i.e. non-person entities).